# Why is a factorial recursive function iterating from lowest to highest number and not from highest to lowest number?

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

I have this simple recursive function, which is calculating the factorial of a number. The result is good and it works like a charm.

```
def factorial(y):
  if y == 0:
    return 1

  elif y == 1:
    return 1

  else:
    result = y * factorial(y - 1)
    print(result)

return result
```

To understand the process I've added the **print(result)** function to see the value of the result variable at each iteration of the recursive function.

The output is:
2 
6 
24 
120

I was expecting this output instead :
120 
24 
6 
2

So, why is my recursive function iterating from the lowest number to the highest and not from the highest to the lowest number ?

Comment: Just trace the calls and you'll see why. You recursively call factorial *before* the print statement.

Comment: More to the point, you can't print the value of `factorial(y)` before `factorial(y-1)` is called, because `factorial(y)` is defined *by* the value of `factorial(y-1)`.

Comment: It the output would have been as you expected, it could have stopped immediately with that 120. There would be no more need to get any other result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner-most call finishes first, so that one prints first.

The outer-most call is only ready once all the inner calls finish, so it necessarily has to be printed only after the inner calls finish.

Try this for funsies:

```
def factorial(y, level=0):
  if y == 0:
    return 1

  elif y == 1:
    return 1

  else:
    print(level*" ", "pre-call, y=", y)
    result = y * factorial(y - 1, level=level+2)
    print(level*" ", "post-call, result=", result)

  return result


factorial(5)
```

Output is:

```
 pre-call, y= 5
   pre-call, y= 4
     pre-call, y= 3
       pre-call, y= 2
       post-call, result= 2
     post-call, result= 6
   post-call, result= 24
 post-call, result= 120
```

The nesting helps show the recursion level.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. By the way do you know if there is a way (like a software) to see the step by step path of a script execution ? Could be helpful to see the actual process as the script is running.

Comment: @PhpDoe In general, that's what debuggers are for, but depending on your environment it might be a hassle to set up. For a quick way and easy way to do you could use the package [pysnooper](https://pypi.org/project/PySnooper/).

Answer (score 1):

When `result = y * factorial(y - 1)` is evaluated, the multiplication can only take place when both operands are evaluated first. So *first* the recursive call has to be made. This means that no multiplication will take place before **all** recursive calls have been initiated. Only when the recursion "unwinds" and the callers get their needed operand value for it, will the multiplications be evaluated.

In other words, it is "on the way back", out of recursion that the multiplication operator is accumulating the factors (left-side operands) with the previous product (right-side operand) into a new product.